# Importing Mathematica code in TexShop

Tags: texshop, wolfram-mathematica

I am using TEXShop on my Mac and I need to import some Mathematica input and output to TEXShop. I did some research on the internet where I found some useful tools that could help but I did not find anything specifically for TexShop. Is there some kind of elegant package that might help here?

I know I can use `\usepackage{lstlistings}` but I do not particularly like this one. Any other suggestions?

Thank you!
Cheers.

Comment: Packages `minted` or  `tcolorbox` that provides nice boxes for code display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [pygments-mathematica package](https://github.com/rsmenon/pygments-mathematica) to get nice syntax highlighting with `minted`.  Usage with LaTeX is described on the page I linked to.